# How to enter Multiple entries in .pgpass file?

Tags: bash, postgresql, passwords

I am supposed to execute same psql command from a bash script on 5 remote machines using a username and password.

I have read that we have to pass the credentials in .pgpass file and use the -w option while executing the psql command.

But how can I execute the same command on the 5 machines using the same .pgpass file?

Answer (score 18):

You can add multiple entries in .pgpass file for e.g.

syntax:

```
hostname:port:database:username:password
```

sample file:

```
test.net:5432:testdb:testuser:testpass
test1.net:5432:testdb1:testuser1:testpass1
test2.net:5432:testdb2:testuser2:testpass2
```

Make sure the permission of .pgpass file is set to 0600

```
chmod 0600 .pgpass
```

Comment: But how do I tell the bash script or the psql command on which entry to use while connecting to postgresql since there will be multiple entires

Comment: you need to connect using : username, hostname, dbname and don't have to provide the password. Psql will use password from .pgpass to connect to the database. see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/libpq-pgpass.html

Comment: @user5241806 This is a nicely written answer and a good comment from abhish_gl. Is there a reason why this answer isn't accepted?

Comment: Some tricks: You can use globbing in the pgpass file so that when you use it with psql or some other tool it will essentially pattern match the host, port,database, user and find the first match. If you're creating one of these on windows for linux or use in docker make sure it is LF not CRLF terminated lines. If you are copying or adding one of these within a dockerfile, make sure to rebuild the docker container after any changes. If you are creating this for use on windows, use a pgpass.conf file instead. see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html

Answer (score 6):

You can also use wildcards too (such as *) which is particularly handy for the database.

This means that for the pgpassfile syntax:

```
hostname:port:database:username:password
```

Can be used with value such as:

```
my-host:5432:*:my-username:my-plaintext-password
```

To enable you to connect to all databases on the server using the same credential. If you need a different credential for specific databases, then use more rows preceding this one.

Comment: The wildcard is very handy. Also, you can add comment lines that begin with #